# logical calculation using &, ~ in sybase

Tags: logic, sybase, logical-operators

I am executing the below statements.

SELECT 10 & ~3 . this gives the output as 8
SELECT 10 & ~5 . this gives the output as 10
SELECT 10 & ~2 . this gives the output as 8

Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is bitwise operations, and ~ is inverse.

```
3 is the same as 0011 in binary, and inverse of that is 1100
2 is the same as 0010 in binary, and inverse of that is 1101
5 is the same as 0101 in binary, and inverse of that is 1010
10 is the same as 1010 in binary.

10 & ~3 => 1010 & 1100 = 1000 => 8
10 & ~5 => 1010 & 1010 = 1010 => 10
10 & ~2 => 1010 & 1101 = 1000 => 8
```

bitwise is bit for bit

you can think in decimal as well, but you have to have your mindset in binary as well (sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128...). 10 consist of "8 | 2" and 3 consist of "1 | 2". Inverse of 3 is all but "1 | 2". Common part between 10 and 3 is 2 so you will have all parts from 10 that is not in 3, thus giving us 8.